# Unity3D: Error when creating Grid layout with List<Transfrom>

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, transform, grid-layout

Unity3D 2018.2

> Problem: Grid not being populated by list, not responding correctly to
>   the List<> being filled with Transforms, contains at least 1 item in List<> so it should not be empty. Something is not being transferred right

I'm trying to create a Grid Layout in a scroll view, which is filled with buttons containing transforms kept in a List<>

I get the transforms from checking a GameObject which will usually have 0-25 child transforms in it.

Once it gets all the child transforms from the parent's GameObject, check which child has a tag called "Satellite". After fill the Grid with the List<> containing those certain gameObject.transforms.

Clicking the buttons in the grid should contain the transform, for example OnMouseEnter() in the  script if I use Debug.Log(transform.name) it should display it.

Here is the code I'm using which contain no errors, the grid is empty so I'm not receiving the transforms correctly but I don't know what is wrong with the code. Thank you for the help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SatelliteGridControl : MonoBehaviour {

private List<Transform> satelliteListFromPlanet;

[SerializeField]
private GameObject buttonTemplate;
[SerializeField]
private GridLayoutGroup gridGroup;
[SerializeField]
private Sprite[] iconSprites;

// Use this for initialization
void OnEnable()
{
    getSatellitesInPlanet();

    satelliteListFromPlanet = new List<Transform>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= satelliteListFromPlanet.Count; i++)
    {
        SatTransfrom newSatellite = new SatTransfrom();
        newSatellite.iconSprite = iconSprites[Random.Range(0, iconSprites.Length)];

        satelliteListFromPlanet.Add(newSatellite);
    }

    GenInventory();
}

//  Get Satellites
private void getSatellitesInPlanet()
{
    satelliteListFromPlanet = new List<Transform>();

    //  Get current planet
    Transform currentPlanet = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<HandleCamera>().targetToLookAt;

    //  Check inside for satellites
    foreach (Transform satellite in currentPlanet)
    {
        //  Check transform for tag
        if (satellite.CompareTag("Satellite"))
        {
            //  Add each transform from planet to array
            satelliteListFromPlanet.Add(satellite);
        }
    }
}

//  Handle Grid
private void GenInventory()
{
    if (satelliteListFromPlanet.Count < 6)
    {
        gridGroup.constraintCount = satelliteListFromPlanet.Count;
    }
    else
    {
        gridGroup.constraintCount = 5;
    }

    foreach (SatTransfrom sat in satelliteListFromPlanet)
    {
        GameObject newButton = Instantiate(buttonTemplate) as GameObject;
        newButton.SetActive(true);

        newButton.GetComponent<SatelliteButton>().SetIcon(sat.iconSprite);
        newButton.transform.SetParent(buttonTemplate.transform.parent, false);
    }
 }

 public class SatTransfrom : Transform
 {
    public Sprite iconSprite;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `OnEnable` you first call `getSatellitesInPlanet` to populate your list `satelliteListFromPlanet`.

But right after you finished you call

```
satelliteListFromPlanet = new List<Transform>();
```

Which resets your list to a new empty one.

Than you have a loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= satelliteListFromPlanet.Count; i++)
{ //... }
```

But since `satelliteListFromPlanet` is an empty list at this moment nothing happens.

And finally when you call `GetInventory` your list is still empty so

```
foreach (SatTransfrom sat in satelliteListFromPlanet)
```

Is executed never since there are no elements in `satelliteListFromPlanet`.

---

Now to the second problem:

You have

```
for(int i = 0; i< sateliteLostFromPlanet.Count; i++)
```

But inside of this loop you do

```
sateliteListFromPlanet.Add(xy);
```

... So what happens to your List during running this loop?

It grows bigger 1 elememt each loop so your loop condition `i < sateliteListFromPlanet.Count` will **allways** be true since after every execution your list is 1 element longer and `i` is `1` bigger!

Result: You add more and more elements to the same list "forever" until your device runs out of memory.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, so simple it was clearing my List but now when it runs I get an "Out Of Memory" error and program stays frozen. Whats happening?

Comment: Now I understand, so I would need a separate List<> for holding `SatTransfrom newSatellite = new SatTransfrom();` ? or do I even need to keep that List<> ?

Comment: Yes I would work with two different lists. However I still wonder if this will work at all since `Transform` is a MonoBehaviour component which you can't simply create using `new` as far as I know...

Comment: Yes you are correct. It would say `cannot convert Transform to SatTransfrom` so I'm a bit stuck here.

Comment: Well this exceeds the scope of your question but: Why do you require the `SatTransform` to inherit from `Transform` at all? You could simply make it a "normal" class (`public class SatTransform { //...}`) and have a `List<SatTransform>` to only save the sprites (or directly a `List<Sprite>` if this is the only data to store)...